# Detect outputs in closure compiler's gulp plugin

Tags: gulp, closures

I am using gulp and google closure compiler e.g.:

```
var compilerPackage = require('google-closure-compiler');
var closureCompiler = compilerPackage.gulp();

gulp.task('js-compile', function () {
    return closureCompiler({
        js: './src/js/**.js',
        externs: compilerPackage.compiler.CONTRIB_PATH + '/externs/jquery-1.9.js',
        compilation_level: 'ADVANCED',
        warning_level: 'VERBOSE',
        language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT',
        language_out: 'ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT',
        output_wrapper: '(function(){\n%output%\n}).call(this)',
        js_output_file: 'output.min.js'
   })
  .src() // needed to force the plugin to run without gulp.src
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});
```

Is it possible do detect outputs (warning and error)? For example like this:

```
.on("error", function(err) {})
.on("warning", function(warn) {});
```

Thank you for your help